# WG Client Connects To WG Server, But No Connectivity

Tags: wireguard

I am on an Ubuntu 20.04 client and I have a Debian 10.5 server. I cannot connect to the server(the handshake never completes).

I installed enabled Wireguard Debug Logging in my linux kernels (local & remote machines).  NOTE: only works for linux kernels 5.6+

```
sudo su -
echo module wireguard +p > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control
```

Then I attempted to connect from client to server using:
`systemctl start wg-quick@wg-client1.service`

during the failed attempt, ran on my local machine 
`sudo dmesg -wH`

Which showed that the "handshake" between the machines is failing. From there I stopped the wireguard connection on the local machine (in order to have web access) `systemctl stop wg-quick@wg-client1.service`

On the remote machine I ran:
`dmesg -wH`

which showed me:
`wireguard: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel`

So, I also used:
`apt install --reinstall wireguard-dkms`

**Status Quo:** This is the content of my .conf files on remote and local

**Server** wg0.conf

```
# cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = gBPkvAe5wglKlw7xEG7GGAMZHhnuw3ihJPYaleMS21o=


[Peer]
PublicKey = F7b4g+DXHYlw/FZ/dQwtHsUz5axBhGVeHnk3WPXZj1s=
AllowedIPs = 10.10.10.2/24
```

**Client** wg-cliet1.conf

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wireguard/wg-client1.conf
[Interface]
Address = 10.10.10.2/24
DNS = 10.10.10.1
PrivateKey = iIszA9knBCSfvq9scotlSwOEPnyyOZ1nVRjIK3O4+mo=


[Peer]
PublicKey = k7LWMskgQWyeMX8kQwv5E3JnXj9UoInurrZZOntBZUo=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = xx.xx.xxx.xxx:51820
PersistentKeepAlive = 25
```

I am probably making a silly mistake somewhere.. but I have been staring at the screen too long to find it.

Comment: WireGuard does not _connect_. Invalid traffic is silently discarded. So your configuration must be incorrect. I suggest you compare the outputs of `wg` on both ends to verify endpoints and keys.

Comment: Also `tcpdump` on the server, maybe, to e.g. see if port forwarding is working if behind NAT

Comment: I have double checked my configs.. inside and out.. everything is correct according to this tutorial.. https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/wireguard-vpn-server-ubuntu#comment-208230  ... Does it matter if SSH is on port 22 or different port?  That is only difference that I can find.

Comment: Confirmed my suspicion client is trying to connect on ssh port 22.  Does anyone know how to force client to connect on a different designated ssh port?

Comment: I have a hard time following your updates. How is SSH related at all? WireGuard uses UDP and nothing else. If the handshake is failing, I can only repeat: Your configuration must be incorrect. Please provide both server and client configuration with their real keys. You can replace the keys later.

Comment: @DanielB  give me a few minutes.. I will post what you requested... I went ahead changed the ssh port back to 22 to test and wg still failed.. and dmesg gave me a different message:  [  +0.714353] wireguard: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: You are using different subnets in the client conf and server conf (10.0.0.0/24 vs 10.10.10.0/24) btw

Comment: You should include those two conf files in addition to / instead of those less relevant / irrelevant mess.

Comment: I don't see "10.0.0.0/24"... are you referring to AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0?  Will clean up the post after I figure out the answer

Comment: See `ip -4 address` in the two sets of client logs.

Comment: Even the address in the server log is `10.10.10.6` instead of `10.10.10.1`

Comment: ok.. let me go back and edit the post.. I already changed the subnet addresses on local and remote...  so the last set of conf files that I posted are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124513/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-yupthatguy).